# react-datepicker with custom input for user input not working

Tags: reactjs, input, onchange, react-datepicker

there is a `CustomCalendarComponent` which uses `react-datepicker` shown below:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        start :new Date()
    }
    this.handleStartChange = this.handleStartChange.bind(this);
}
handleStartChange (start) {
    start = start || this.state.start;
    this.setState({ start })
};    
render() {
    return(
        <>
            <span>Start</span>
            <DatePicker 
            selected = {this.state.start}
            selectsStart
            startDate = {this.state.start}
            endDate = {this.state.end}
            onChange = {this.handleStartChange}
            customInput = { <CustomCalendarComponent />}
            dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
            openToDate = {this.state.start}
            showMonthDropdown
            showYearDropdown
            dropdownMode = 'select'
            />
        </>
    )
}
```

it has a `customInput` as shown below:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
}

static propTypes = {
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    value: PropTypes.string,
    placeholderText: PropTypes.string
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <FormGroup className="mb-0">
          <InputGroup>
            <Input
              className={this.props.className}
              placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
              onClick={this.props.onClick}
              value={this.props.value}
              onChange={this.props.onChange}
              type="input"
            />
            <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
              <InputGroupText
                className="dateIconStyle"
                onClick={this.props.onClick}
              >
                <i className={"icon-calendar"} />
              </InputGroupText>
            </InputGroupAddon>
          </InputGroup>
        </FormGroup>
        </div>
      );
}
```

everything is fine as long as user selects date from calendar, when user tries to type the date, it does not work. when user starts to delete the input it does not work properly. I tried a lot and spent nearly a whole day, but can not find the problem, I found [this issue](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/426) on github, but no luck, what is it?

Comment: You are using an input box for date input. So, with the valid date input, it will work as it is custom component inside datepicker. But when you are trying to edit the date as text, it may become an invalid date as you go on editing it. So, that might throw an exception inside the date picker and will not work.

Comment: @Vrishank what should I do that user can type properly?

Comment: Not sure about your specific case but you will need implementation something like this: When the user is typing the date input, the validation on that should happen only after the date input is complete and not on every keystroke.

Comment: @Vrishank if I remove `cusotmInput` it works propery, I thought it might be because of something on `customInput`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a custom component for dates, you need to manage all the states of custom input field differently from the date-picker properties. Also only when the input is valid, you need to set it to datepicker. Working code similar to your case below:

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CustomCalendarComponent from './CustomCalendarComponent';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import './App.css';
import moment from 'moment';

const momentDateFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      dpDate: moment().toDate(),
      ipDate: moment().format(momentDateFormat)
    }
  }

  handleDPChange (val) {
    this.setState({dpDate:val, ipDate:moment(val).format(momentDateFormat)});
  }; 

  handleIpChange(val){
    let d = moment(val, momentDateFormat);
    if(d.isValid()){
        this.setState({dpDate:d.toDate()});
    }
    this.setState({ipDate:val});
}

  render(){
    return (
    <>
            <span>Start</span><br/>
            <DatePicker
              selected={this.state.dpDate}
              onChange={value => this.handleDPChange(value)}
              customInput={ <CustomCalendarComponent
                ipDate={this.state.ipDate}
                handleIpChange={(val)=>this.handleIpChange(val)}
              />}
              dateFormat={"MM/dd/yyyy"}
              showMonthDropdown
              showYearDropdown
              dropdownMode = 'select'
            />
        </>
  );
    }
}

export default App;
```

CustomCalendarComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
export default class CustomCalendarComponent extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <br/>
                <span>CUSTOM DATE {this.props.ipDate}</span>
                <br/>
                <input
                    onClick={this.props.onClick}
                    value={this.props.ipDate}
                    onChange={(e)=>this.props.handleIpChange(e.target.value)}
                    type="input"
                />
            </div>
          );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass all the props to your Custom Input as below :

```
<FormGroup className="mb-0">
      <InputGroup>
        <Input
           otherprops...
          {...this.props}
        />
        <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
          <InputGroupText
            className="dateIconStyle"
            onClick={this.props.onClick}
          >
            <i className={"icon-calendar"} />
          </InputGroupText>
        </InputGroupAddon>
      </InputGroup>
    </FormGroup>
```